# How to keep count of method calls within function executed? Python

Tags: python, string, counter

My question is how to keep count of "method calls within function"?

I mean in the example below the replacement activity has happened twice inside the function. But all I can do is run a counter to check:how many times the function has been executed.

```
def replace (newString,i=[0]):
    oldString = 'This is word. This is another sample word.'
    newString = oldString.replace('word', 'WORD')
    print(newString)
    i[0]+=1
    return i[0]
```

How to count the execution of method calls within the function and throw an output to keep track of it in python?

```
Output: 
This is WORD. This is another sample WORD.
1

Expected output:
This is WORD. This is another sample WORD.
2
```

Comment: It doesn't really make sense because the `oldString.replace()` method happens only once. so why would it be 2?

Comment: I agree, but how to keep track of method call? Cause method call replaces twice.

Comment: It seems like you're just looking for the number of elements replaced, i.e. the number of times `'word'` occurs in `oldString`

Comment: You might check out the [profiling tools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) python offers.

Comment: It replaces two occurrences but it is called only once.

Comment: That function's usefulness is very questionable to begin with. E.g. the `newString` parameter is never used.

Comment: I want to count the occurrences. Would profiling tools help?

Comment: `oldString.count("word")` will return the number of times `word` will be replaced with `WORD`

Comment: Thanks. This solves a specific aspect of the question. Still interested in counting "method call" without specifying the "word" by hardcoding.

Comment: I'm not clear on what is it that you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks your answer helped. I will start a new question on the other topic. That is different need.

Comment: ok. next time don't post someone else's answer as yours (:

Answer (score 0):

**RegEx Approach**

```
import re
def replace(newString):
    oldString = 'This is word. This is another sample word.'
    newString = (re.sub('word', 'WORD', oldString))
    print newString
    print len(re.findall("WORD", newString))
```

Output:

```
This is WORD. This is another sample WORD.
2
```